# Конвертация DataColumn[] в схему MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

У меня есть массив `DataColumn[]` полученный из одной очень старой СУБД. Мне надо по этому массиву создать таблицу MySQL. В принципе мне кажется в нем есть все данные для этого. Мне не надо никаких усложнений типа первичных и вторичных ключей, индексов и т.п. Только основную схему. `DataColumn` сам по себе уже содержит название столбца и информацию о его типе (в т.ч. nullable и т.п.). Может есть уже готовый способ воссоздать из этого схему MySQL чтобы не делать это вручную, смаппливая каждый .NET тип на базу?

Comment: Нет, DataColumn содержит лишь информацию о типах платформы .NET. Он не знает, из какого движка СУБД были получены исходные данные. Соответственно, невозможно однозначно восстановить их. Боюсь, придется делать маппинг вручную. Не исключено, что можно найти какую-нибудь библиотеку, выполняющую такое преобразование именно для mysql, но ручная корректировка результата наверняка все равно понадобится.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так я об этом и говорю. Подскажите мне такую библиотеку!

Comment: Находим табличку маппинга типов между .net и mysql ([1](http://elaanet.blogspot.com/2013/02/mapping-net-data-types-to-mysql-data.html), [2](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/datatypemapping.html)), а дальше просто генерируем sql. Делов на 5 минут, имхо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну да. Вообщем-то так я уже и начал делать безо всяких таблиц. Хмм, ну ладно. Раз другого выхода нет...